# In triangle ABC prove two lines are perpendicular.

Tags: geometry

[image]

In triangle ABC , D and E are the feet of heights from C and B. Prove the radius OA of circumscribed circle is perpendicular to DE.

Note: I used this as an statement to solve another problem in this site.

Comment: So $AB \perp CD$ and $BE \perp AC$, is that right?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution:

This is actually an easy one. I give you the steps you need to follow to prove what you want.

[image: Fig. 1]

Let $\measuredangle ABC=\beta$.

Since $BDC$ is a right-angled triangle, $\measuredangle DCB=90^0-\beta$.

Since $\measuredangle AOC$ is the subtended angle at the center of circle, $\measuredangle AOC=2\beta$.

Since $AOC$ is an isosceles triangle, $\measuredangle AOC=90^0-\beta$.

Consider the right-angled triangle $BEC$. Its circumcircle has its center at the midpoint of $BC$ and its radius is equal to $\frac{BC}{2}$. Now, consider the right-angled triangle $BDC$. Its circumcircle also has its center at the midpoint of $BC$ and its radius is equal to $\frac{BC}{2}$. This proves that both triangles have the same circumcircle. Therefore, $BDEC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Since all angles (in our case $\measuredangle DCB$ and $\measuredangle DEB$ inscribed in a circle (in our case the circumcircle of the quadrilateral $BDEC$) and subtended by the same chord (in our case $BD$) are equal, i.e. $\measuredangle DEB=90^0-\beta$.

Since $\measuredangle BEA$ is a right angle, $\measuredangle AED=90^0-\measuredangle DEB=\beta$.

Name the intersection point of the two lines $AO$ and $DE$ as $F$. Now, consider the triangle $AEF$. We know that two of its angles, i.e. $\measuredangle AEF=\beta$ and $\measuredangle FAE=90^0-\beta$. Therefore, the remaining angle $\measuredangle EFA$is equal to $90^0$ and this proves that $OA$ is perpendicular to $DE$.

Comment: This is in tern another question,: prove that quadrilateral BDEC is cyclic. Could you include this in your answer.

Comment: If you mean $\angle OAE=\angle DEF=\angle DCE$, it is possible only if $O$ is on DC.

Comment: I attached a diagram to my answer for you to refer. What I mean was $\measuredangle OAE = \measuredangle OCA$. This is because $OC=OA=radius$.

Comment: But OCA is not equal to DCB.

Comment: @sirous As I promised several hours ago, I just posted the complete solution for you to peruse.